# UITableView in UIViewController in Xcode5 not working

Tags: uitableview, xcode5

I've done this successfully before in past apps under Xcode4 but it doesn't seem to work anymore in Xcode5. In short, I like to add a `UITableView` into a `UIViewController`. Part of the process requires that I add as properties into the cell.h any GUI elements that it contains such as `UILabel`. The problem is, I'm no longer able to ctrl-drag those elements into the cell.h.

**Main.storyboard**

`UIViewController`, `UITableView`, `UITableViewCell`

- The `UITableView` has the `UIViewController` as datasource and delegate.
- Please assume I'm using the correct delegate methods in the ViewController.m file.

**testViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "testCell.h"

@interface testViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

**testViewController.m**

```
@synthesize myTableView;
```

**testCell.h**

Issue: Unable to ctrl-drag a `UILabel` from the cell into this file as I've done on past apps.

**testCell.m**

Nothing added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by manually typing in the IBOutlet property and linking it that way.

ctrl-drag still does not work FYI.